# Can I use SiriKit with an independent Apple Watch App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watch, sirikit

I'm building an independent Watch App where I want to ask Siri canned questions about my workout. However, I can't find any resources (App Dev site, tutorials, articles, etc) for how to create *JUST* an independent Watch App (with no corresponding iPhone app). Is this possible?

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like you _can_ [create independent watch apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps). And it looks like you can [create a SiriKit intents app extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension) for independent watch apps too (note the "Important" text box towards the bottom).

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Comment: I sadly couldn't get this to work. I believe you can create Siri "Intents" but not the entire SiriKit with *just* an independent Watch App. Last I tried was in April, so maybe it has been updated! Best of luck. :)

Comment: I'm experiencing issues getting siri authorization on an independent watch application. I just met with an Apple engineer during WWDC to get an idea of what was going on, and it seems like Apple has a bug on their end. I filed a ticket, but I was curious if anybody has any new information regarding this behavior?